# migrate from ThinkingSphinx to Elasticsearch on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I want to move to Elasticsearch from ThinkingSphenx on rails application.

I use simple and complex search like :
`ThinkingSphinx.search(query, options)`
and
`ThinkingSphinx.facets(query, options)`

so how to make the change on these example ?
the `search` is simple but I can't get how implement `facets`!

it's good to get an example how to.

Comment: May be will be better if you will provide description of result you want to achieve. As example I can help you with elasticsearch but I know nothing about what ThinkingSphinx.facets are for.

Comment: Facet Searches are search summaries - they provide a breakdown of result counts for each of the defined categories/facets.
check this [freelancing-gods](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/facets.html)

Comment: it looks like summary aggregation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html

Comment: Also it can be combined with terms aggregation - for grouping by term, and then counting sum. To provide solution need to know you document structure and what need to be calculated. In rails you can form query with aggregation - and call ‘.aggregations’ in response to get aggregations response.